# How to change this Google Chrome layout?

Tags: google-chrome

My **new tab** page in Google Chrome looks like this :

[image]

As you can see , it has some sort of custom skin.How do I reset this back to the default skin ?

Comment: You obviously have some extension installed. Go to Tools->Extensions and find the culprit.

Comment: Wow, I really don’t understand the hostility to this question. ಠ_ಠ

Answer (score 1):

Open the page `chrome://settings` and click the button `[Reset to default theme]`:

[image: Screenshot of Chrome theme settings]

Answer (score 0):

Go to **extensions** page  (*Tools->Extensions*) or  **chrome://extensions/** .You will probably find an extension that does it to you.Hit **uninstall**.Voila.